# The App Store is not showing my In-App Purchase list

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

After I released my app, the in-app purchases list is not displaying in the App Store.

I implemented IAP in my app - it is working fine in the app itself, but it doesn't show the available in-app purchases in the iOS App Store's list of available purchases.

What should I be doing to make the available purchases visible to the App Store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about the App Store, and [is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are seeing in the iTunes Store is the list of your top in app purchases. If none of your in app purchases are sold, they will not show up. Secondly it takes some time for this list to appear, so be patient and it will appear automatically after purchases are made.

Comment: yes the in App list is display is taking time after releasing the app